# Why don't @interface, @imp... and @end require a semicolon at the end of the line? Also, are there other instances where this is the case?

Tags: objective-c

I know the "@" symbol is used to show Objective-C keywords, but I don't understand why some of these keywords require a semicolon, while some don't.

Namely, as far as I can see; @interface, @implementation, and @end don't require a semicolon

```
@interface EditorPrintView ()
@property  ImageDocument* editorDoc;
@property  NSColor* backgroundColor;

@property BOOL paginate;
@property CGFloat scale;
@end

@class ImageController;

@implementation EditorPrintView
...
@end
```

Does anybody know of any specific reason why this is?  If this is just an artifact of history, then I'll buy it, but I wasn't able to create a good search query to find any answers.

Comment: Think of them kind of like curly braces. They mark a "block" and don't need the semicolons.

Comment: Does the compiler just identify these keywords and put in curly braces on it's own?  And are these the only instances where a semicolon isn't required?

Comment: Curly braces are not added. I was just offering a way to think about those specific keywords.

Comment: Gotcha.  But if I put in a semicolon, it still compiles?  So the compiler has it hard coded that if it sees one of these keywords, it won't nag about a semicolon?

Comment: In C languages, you can do `;;;;;;` and it just looks at those as empty expressions.

Comment: While I know that probably is the answer, and it is just that simple, but I was just wondering if there was more to it

Comment: You'd have to ask the language designers.

Comment: I don't see any good way to answer this question other than with "because they don't". Curiosity is fine and good, but what information do you really want here?

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess a better way to phrase my curiosity-- is why not just require no semi colons for any "@" keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only speculate on the motivation of Objective-C's designer, Brad Cox. (I suppose we could also try to contact him…)

I believe Brad Cox originally implemented Objective-C as a preprocessor that transformed Objective-C into plain C in a fairly straightforward way. It might have been easier to write the preprocessor by not requiring semicolons.

For example, keep in mind that `@interface` can be followed by a brace-enclosed block of declarations, e.g.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    int _count;
    IBOutlet NSView *_view;
}

...
@end
```

Perhaps it was easier to write the preprocessor to handle this optional block by not allowing a semicolon after the `@interface` declaration.

Also, since the @-declarations are not part of the plain C language, perhaps Brad Cox chose to treat them more like the C preprocessor's #-directives, which were (at the time Objective-C was invented) handled by a preprocessor and don't require (or generally even allow) semicolons. So `@interface` … `@end` is like `#if` … `#endif`.

These days, it would probably be trivial to write the compiler either way (allowing or disallowing semicolons), but there's no reason to change that part of the language now.

As for other directives that don't require a semicolon: there are `@protocol` declarations, and there's `@optional`, `@required`, `@public`, `@private`, `@package`, and `@protected`.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)  I was using `@class` earlier and forgot to put a semicolon, then was just wondering why that was even required.  I understand that maybe the question is opinion based but I really appreciate your time here.